# Alfresco and webapp tomcat in parallel

Tags: web-services, tomcat, web-applications, alfresco, tomcat8

I'm running Alfresco in

> localhost:8080/share

But I don't have Alfresco inside the folder of the tomcat like:

> $tomcathome/webapps/alfresco

It runs independently. However, if I shutdown tomcat in the tomcat folder, Alfresco goes down.

So, if I want to put a webapp running in the same time with Alfresco in the tomcat (different ports or not), how can I do that?

If I try to call, for example,

> localhost:8080/my-app

this display to me a white page but if I shutdown alfresco, It works...

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to deploy your second web application to the same tomcat instance as alfresco. Alternatively you may chose to change ports on one of your two tomcat instances by playing with the server.xml file inside your `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf` folder.

However, if you chose to change alfresco's ports that **WILL** break share authentification (and the whole proxy endpoint) unless you follow [this guide](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Changing_Default_Port_Configuration) to let share know about your changes!

---

**UPDATE :** That guide is a bit outdated (before the SOLR era), for more up-to-date guide, check [this](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/deploy-contextpath.html) and [this](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/share-change-port.html)!

Comment: But for the first option (because I already break multiple times the authentication :( ) "You may want to deploy your second web application to the same tomcat instance as alfresco. " You know how can I make this part?

Comment: simply put your `my-app.war` in your `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`

Comment: But this display to me a white page. Only if I shutdown Alfresco, this works.

Comment: `-_-` Use the same `$TOMCAT_HOME` as in alfresco !! Just make sure to deploy your war to the same folder containing `alfresco.war` and `share.war`